# How to find the days having a drawdown greater than X bips?

Tags: kdb

What would be the most idiomatic way to find the days with a drawdown greater than X bips? I again worked my way through some queries but they become boilerplate ... maybe there is a simpler more elegant alternative:

```
q)meta quotes
c   | t f a
----| -----
date| z    
sym | s    
year| j    
bid | f    
ask | f    
mid | f
```

then I do:

```
bips:50;
`jump_in_bips xdesc distinct select date,jump_in_bips from (update date:max[date],jump_in_bips:(max[mid]-min[mid])%1e-4 by `date$date from quotes where sym=accypair) where jump_in_bips>bips;
```

but this will give me the days for which there has been a jump in that number of bips and not only the drawdowns.

I can of course put this result above in a temporary table and do several follow up selects like:

```
select ... where mid=min(mid),date=X
select ... where mid=max(mid),date=X
```

to check that the `max(mid)` was *before* the `min(mid)` ... is there a simpler, more idiomatic way?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible/numerical example? Your question requires too many assumptions on our side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `maxs` is the key function here, which allows you to maintain a running historical maximum, and you can compare your current value to that maximum. If you have some table `quote` which contains some series of mids (`mids`) and timestamps (`date`), the following query should return the days where you saw a drawdown greater than a certain value:

```
key select by `date$date from quote 
  where bips<({(maxs[x]-x)%1e-4};mid) fby `date$date
```

The lambda `{(maxs[x]-x)%1e-4}` is doing the comparison at each point to the historical maximum and checking if it's greater than `bips`, and `fby` lets you apply the `where` clause group-wise by date. Grouping with a `by` on date and taking the key will then return the days when this occurred.

If you want to preserve the information for the max drawdown you can use an update instead:

```
select max draw by date from 
  (update draw:(maxs[mid]-mid)%1e-4 by date from @[quote;`date;`date$])
  where bips<draw
```

The date is updated separately with a direct modification to quote, to avoid repeated casting.

Comment: Excellent thank you! The second alternative produces a 'length error though ... this bit `@[quotes;`date;`date$]`

Comment: I'm not totally sure on the structure of your table - you could replace this ``@[quotes;`date;`date$] `` with ``update `date$date from quotes``.

Answer (score 1):

Difference between `max` and `min` mids for given date may be both increase and drawdown. Depending on if `max` mid precedes `min`. Also, as far a `sym` columns exists, I assume you may have different symbols in the table and want to get drawdowns for all of them.

For example if there are 3 quotes for given day and sym: `1.3000 1.2960 1.3010`, than the difference between 2nd and 3rd is 50 pips, but this is increase.

The next query can be used to get dates and symbols with drawdown higher than given threshold

```
select from 
(select drawdown: {max maxs[x]-x}mid 
    by date, sym from quotes) 
where drawdown>bips*1e-4
```

`{max maxs[x]-x}` gives maximum drawdown for given date by subtracting each mid for maximum of preceding mids.